# invalid cell value Error when reading in data from MySql using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am trying to read in some data from MySql database using C# using `MySqlDataAdapter`. Below is my code:

```
private MySqlConnection connection;
private string ConnectionString;

public void MySqlConnectionHandler(string SQL_QUERY)
{
    try
    {
        ConnectionString = " SERVER = 127.0.0.1;"
                           + "DATABASE = my_database;" 
                           + "UID=uid;"
                           + "PASSWORD=password";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(SQL_QUERY,connection);
        MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        connection.Open();
        DataSet dbdataset = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dbdataset);
        DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook("MyExcelFile.xls", dbdataset);
        connection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Connected");
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "MySQL Query Failure");
    }
}
```

The invalid cell value error occurs  when  `DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook("MyExcelFile.xls", dbdataset);` is run. I have checked the connection to the database and it was fine, so I am not sure what is the exact problem.

Comment: because probably the `dbdataset` that you're filling needs to be a DataTable so perhaps you can do `dbdataset.Tables[0]` when filling it

Comment: I tried that but it gave me an error saying cannot find table 0. I assume I need to initialize an instance of table 0 and fill that instead?

Comment: you can just use the fill method on a Datatable create the new instance of DataTable first then apply the fill method to that DataTable

Comment: Your SQL_QUERY might contain columns, which can not be converted correctly (e.g. BLOB-Fields, Array-Fields). Try this method with fewer data or give us some rows of your query.